# Java error declaring serialVersionUID inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, serialversionuid

I'm getting this error that's really frustrating me from this bit of script...

```
    JPanel menu = new JPanel() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            JTextArea output = new JTextArea(5, 30) {

                /**
                 * 
                 */
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 4714318125998709253L;
                this.setEditable(false);
            };
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(output);

//          public void run() {
//              System.out.println("lol");
//              JPanel menu = this;
//              JButton restart = new JButton("Restart");
//              menu.add(restart);
//          }

        };
```

I'm trying to declare setEditable inside of JTextArea output... any ideas?

EDIT:
the error is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Syntax error on token ";", < expected

    at citadelRPG.Server.createAndShowGUI(Server.java:94)
    at citadelRPG.Server.access$0(Server.java:16)
    at citadelRPG.Server$1.run(Server.java:162)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

appearing on the semi-colon of declaring serialVersionUID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
this.setEditable(false);
```

needs to be in method, static initializer or constructor rather than in the class block of the  anonymous implementation of the `JTextArea` `output`. If you really wish to have this implementation inside the `output` class, you can override `isEditable`

```
@Override
public boolean isEditable() {
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This `this.setEditable(false);` needs to defined within the context of a constructor or method. It can't be called outside of these contexts.

I find it extremely strange that people insist on implementing classes in this manner, but that's just me.

Your adding no new functionality to the `JPanel`, so why not just create it, a `JTextarea`, a `JScrollPane` and add them altogether. It will make your code more readable and solve silly mistakes like these.

Personally, a better solution would be...

```
JPanel menu = new JPanel() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
};
JTextArea output = new JTextArea(5, 30) {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4714318125998709253L;
};
output.setEditable(false);
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(output);
menu.add(scrollPane);
```